# Copyright symbol "&#x00A9" is invalid?

Tags: html, eclipse, reserved-words, invalid-characters

I had a simple footer part html in my application to declare my copy right and right reservation. HTML code as:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">

<html> 
<body>
<p>Copyright &#x00A9 from 2013 of Longz Australia<img src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/resources/img/g8626.png">. Tweed Head Self Storage &trade; and its logo/signs <img src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/resources/img/g3039.png"> were registered in Australia. All rights reserved.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Eclipse keep telling me:

```
Invalid character used in text string (Copyright &#x00A9 from 2013 of Longz 
Australia).
```

I tried to replace it with `&copy`, it is the same. But trade mark symbol "&trade" work well in same para. Seems Eclipse don't like to see &copy?

Browser rend it correctly. Only Eclipse keep complaint.

This is not a big issue, but it is annoy me.

Comment: Maybe it just doesn't like when you omit the semicolon

Comment: Do you actually need to encode the character? Maybe you can simply write "© from 2013".

Comment: LOL. Thank you Alexey. Thank you for your advice. © from 2013 works for me. Happy new year!! Mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `&#169;` but `&copy;` should work too

Comment: Those two not work too. Alexey advice "© from 2013" works for me. Thank you, any way.

Comment: Yes, it works for me, put a semicolon afterward. Nice advice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `&#x00A9` is invalid without a trailing semicolon, and so is `&copy`, at least in normal content. You can check this from the HTML specification that you try to conform to.

As an aside, you can enter “©” directly in an HTML document, but that’s a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

please do add a semicolon in the end for your hexadecimal code .